# How to call Crypt() function mono C#?

Tags: mono

i'm in a need of using the unix **Crypt(salt, key)** function in c# code for encrypting
my password using a two character salt and 8 characters key.
In C/C++, we can do so but how to do this in C#.
I'm using **Mono C#** in ubuntu linux.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the complete working program which uses unix crypt:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Test
{   
    [DllImport("libcrypt.so", EntryPoint = "crypt", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern IntPtr UnixCrypt([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string key, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string salt); 

    public static void Main()
    {
        var ptrResult = UnixCrypt("test", "test2");
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptrResult));
    }
}
```

It prints result of crypting with given key and salt. Of course you can put UnixCrypt in any other class. For convenience you can also create method:

```
public static string MyCrypt(string key, string salt)
{
    return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(UnixCrypt(key, salt));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an similar question-
[Encrypt and decrypt a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net)

There is an article on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/DotNetCrypto.aspx), it teaches how you can create an helper class.

Comment: you are not familiar with UNIX Crypt() function i guess. plz google about it and then answer if you can.